# Open Source Amazon EC2?

Tags: open-source, amazon-ec2, rackspace

Are there any open source applications that provide a set of features similar to that of Amazon EC2 or Rackspace Cloud?  Basically, I want a tool that I can install on one or more servers that works with a virtual machine monitor like Xen and lets me create, destroy, and clone virtual machines on the fly using some sort of API.

Comment: You may wish to revise; S3 is a storage service. You're thinking of Amazon EC2.

Comment: ah yes, EC2 is what I meant.  thanks.

Comment: A few years later this is a really great example of why "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow" (because the answers invariably become obsolete as time passes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar to what other posters have mentioned, I would recommend [Eucalyptus](http://open.eucalyptus.com). It can use either Xen or KVM to manage virtual machines through the same Query API that Amazon EC2 provides. It also provides an S3-compatible service for storing files in buckets named Walrus. In case you need proof that you can run it over Xen, here's from the config file for Eucalyptus:

```
# The hypervisor that the Node Controller will interact with in order
# to manage virtual machines.  Currently, supported values are 'kvm'
# and 'xen'.
HYPERVISOR="xen"
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Eucalyptus](http://open.eucalyptus.com/), mentioned in other answers, you might also wish to take a look at [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/).  It's the other major open Amazon AWS-like cloud stack.  It's backed by NASA, RackSpace, Citrix, Intel, AMD and Dell, amongst many others.

*(Declaration of interests: I am presently providing technical consultancy to Citrix; however, I am answering this question in a private capacity.)*

Answer (score 2):

Canonical is the company making Ubuntu. They also Make UEC (Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud) witch is build around Eucalyptus.  The architecture of Eucalyptus was design for maximum compatibility with EC2 (Elastic Cloud Computing).

UEC is open source and very easy to use.  I personaly put my first cloud together using UEC (9.4).

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking into using [Eucalyptus with ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Eucalyptus), I believe that it might even be what amazon are using for their ubuntu based cloud services.

Comment: I don't believe that. any sources?

Comment: Eucalyptus works with Xen or KVM just fine. I'm using it with Xen right now :)

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the clarification, I wasn't aware.